# Service dead but pid file exists on Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, service, amazon-ec2

I created a service `<service-name>` and ran it on an Amazon EC2 instance. This comes up bundled as a part of my private AMI. Upon initial startup, the service works well:

```
$ sudo service <service-name> status
<service-name> (pid 1234) is running...
```

But when I reinstall it, the status then changes to

```
<service-name> dead but pid file exists
```

I tried removing these files:

```
$sudo rm -rf /var/run/service-name/*
$sudo rm -rf /var/lock/subsys/service-name
```

Then reinstalled the service. But still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon inspecting the logs, I found that the `<service-name>` didn't have enough memory. So I upgraded from `T2.Micro` (1 GB memory) to `T2.Small` (2 GB memory) and it fixed the issue.